# What is the run-time complexity in terms of n and m?

Tags: python, time-complexity

This was a coding interview question.
What is the run-time complexity of the following algorithm, in terms of n and m?

```
    def print_all_codes(n, m):
    
        def print_01_codes(current, num_digits):
    
            if num_digits == 0:
    
                print(current)
    
            else:
    
                print_01_codes('0' + current, num_digits - 1)
    
                print_01_codes('1' + current, num_digits - 1)
    
        upper_bound = 0
    
        while True:
    
            for i in range(upper_bound):
    
                print_01_codes('', n)
    
            if upper_bound > m:
    
                break
    
            upper_bound += 1
```

Comment: What is `n` and `m`?

Comment: Are you sure that `i` is nowhere used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while True:

        for i in range(upper_bound):

            print_01_codes('', n)

        if upper_bound > m:

            break

        upper_bound += 1
```

This loop is same as this one:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(i):
       #Function
```

This loop time complexity is like this:
`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + m-1 => (m-1)*(m) / 2 => O(m^2)`
about your #Function:

```
        if num_digits == 0:

            print(current)

        else:

            print_01_codes('0' + current, num_digits - 1)

            print_01_codes('1' + current, num_digits - 1)
```

This is a recursive function and this is like a full binary tree. So it's `O(2^n)`.
Your code Time-complexity is `O(m^2 * 2^n)`.